# Xamarin: Check if any particular app is installed in IOS device

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin.forms, I am able to launch the facebook app using `Device` class like this :

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("fb://profile/page_id"));
```

What if the app is not installed in the device. How can I check if app is not installed in the device.

I have written the above code line in the `try` block, but when the app is not installed still the code runs without any output and exeception. I want to redirect to itunes for installation like this :

```
CrossShare.Current.OpenBrowser("https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/facebook/id284882215/");
```

I am using [Plugin.share](https://github.com/jguertl/SharePlugin) in xamarin.forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [AppLinks](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/app-links/). You have to use rivets for the same.

> Linking to other apps - Instead of opening a web link in a browser
>   directly, you should let the App Links navigation take care of how to
>   open a link.

It's the right way to go. It will handle the navigation to store if not installed and else browser based on your URL.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/app-links/).

```
Rivets.AppLinks.Navigator.Navigate("http://any.old.url");
```

> Your app will now attempt to Navigate to another installed app for the
>   URL using App Links, or will fall back to usingUIApplication.OpenUrl in ios/or will fall back to using an intent with a view action in Android, if no App Link meta data is found, or no
>   apps for the metadata are installed.